What's the proper way to shut down after a kernel panic?
Occasionally, when I resume from a suspend or hibernate state, I experience a kernel panic. In such cases, I usually force a shutdown by holding down the power button. Recently, I've started using the kernel parameter panic=n, which automatically reboots the system after n seconds following a kernel panic.

Is there a difference between these methods?

I’ve learned that it’s possible to load another kernel in preparation for a potential kernel panic, allowing you to save the panic logs. Can this secondary kernel be used to perform a proper shutdown (e.g., stopping systemd services, unmounting the file system, etc.) instead of a forced reboot?



"I’ve learned that it’s possible to load another kernel in preparation ..." - That backup kernel must already be in memory (i.e. "loaded") before the primary kernel panics because you cannot rely on a panic'd kernel to be fully functional. After the panic, unless you could reliably confirm what is still intact, you therefore do not trust the contents of memory. You can save memory contents for a post mortem , but don't trust it for a "proper shutdown".

"Is there a difference between these methods?" - It's a cold boot (power-on reset) versus a warm boot (processor reset). Since main memory is implemented with DRAM, and therefore volatile, there's no practical difference (unless there's a HW quirk that requires a power cycle instead of just a reset).

@sawdust but the HDD/SSD cache should stay alive after a reboot because it would still be powered on. While on shutdown it might be lost. Hopefully drive will not sit with unwritten data in cache and do nothing, but I'd count rebooting as slightly preferable.

@akostadinov - Boot software expects/requires that the hardware to be in a known, quiescent state. So all peripherals are issued a reset during boot.  On reset the drive would abandon current operation(s), discard any pending operations, and reinitialize everything. There is no retained cache as you imagine.

@sawdust, provided some drives attempt to write down write-back cache on power loss, idk how are you so sure they would drop it when they receive a reset, instead of writing it down first.

@akostadinov _ You're conflating two different conditions. A power-fail is considered an unintended and externally-caused event. Whereas a reset command is an explicit directive to cease current operations immediately and reinitialize. There's no ambiguity with a reset command; a device is not allowed to respond with a "please wait while I finish up".  "how are you so sure ..." - Well, I've read the ATA specs, and a long time ago I wrote disk controller firmware.

". A power-fail is considered an unintended and externally-caused event." does that mean that hardware and peripherals are more likely to be damaged or reduce the health of a device only when the computer runs out of power, while they are safer if the system is turned off using the reset button?

@YukiSan - Your questions are a bizarre variation of the XY Problem. Rather than solve why "a resume from a suspend or hibernate state, [you] experience a kernel panic", your major concern seems to be only how to resume after the panic. That's the aftermath. That's the effect, rather than the cause. Why are you ignoring the cause? I don't know if that issue is solvable, but panics should not be considered normal.

I ignore the "cause" because in order to understand the cause, I need to do many trials to be able to meet a certain condition and reproduce it and I am not sure once I know the cause whether I can solve the problem or not (I am not a kernel dev nor an nvidia employee). Actually I'm more worried whether my device will be damaged or not if it experiences kernel panic too often in the future, That's why I'm looking for a way to properly shutdown my computer when a kernel panic attack

@sawdust, could you point at the place where ATA spec mandates that this reinitialization requires write back cache being dropped? The controller may reset and continue using existing data on platter/flash as well in the cache. Modern drives perform background operations afaik which also happens transparent to the rest of the computer. Power loss protection of wd involves "Upon power loss, the Re drive utilizes stored spindle energy to back up the HDD cache to onboard flash". This means on next boot that flash is used to recover cached writes. Does not boot involve an initialization command?

SysRq, Sync x3 and reBoot


Is there a difference between these methods?

No, as the original kernel has completely stopped doing kernel things at that point; literally the only things it's doing are blinking the keyboard LED and counting down that reboot timer. Nothing else is running.

Can this secondary kernel be used to perform a proper shutdown (e.g., stopping systemd services, unmounting the file system, etc.) instead of a forced reboot?

Also no. The secondary kernel won't have any of the filesystem driver's "working data" in memory, for example, nor any references to the previously existing processes – it starts fresh just like any other kernel – in part because it has no good way of knowing which of those data structures are still good vs which of them may have been corrupted by whatever issue led to the panic() to begin with, and in part because scraping such things out of a different kernel is probably too fiddly a process to be worth it.
Your filesystem will usually have its own ways of recovering from a crash, anyway, as will your SQL database and other things.
